# how to compare consecutive string values in a row in data frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I want to fill the value "0" of a specific row with previous value of the same row. So, the logic is that if the next value of the row is "0" then the previous value of the same row will get copied to it.

Example of the row

[image]

and expected result

[image]

The row is a part of pandas data frame. Kindly provide examples of the code. I will appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: In the future please provide dataframes as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) and [`bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.bfill.html)

```
import numpy as np

df['col_name'].replace(0, np.nan).bfill()
```

If your `0` is a string, use

```
df['col_name'].replace("0", np.nan).bfill()
```

`bfill` means you will fill the `NaN`s backwards. You can also fill forwards using [`ffill()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
df['col_name'].replace(0, np.nan).ffill()
```

As noted in comments, you can also set everything at once using `to_replace` arg:

```
df.col.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

---

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,0,5,6,7,0,9]})

col
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   0
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   0
8   9

df.col.replace(0, np.nan).bfill()

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    5.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
6    7.0
7    9.0
8    9.0
```

Notice that once `np.nan` is a `float`, pandas may interpret the column to have dtype float. However, you can always set explicitly the type back to `int` using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
df.col.replace(0, np.nan).bfill().astype(int)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    5
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    9
8    9
```

Comment: You are awesome. Tons of thanks.

Comment: @Deya thank you! Glad I could help :) Please consider [Accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if t helped !

Comment: You can avoid the intermedate `np.nan` replacement: `df.col.replace(to_replace=0, method='bfill')`.  This will also prevent the cast to `float`

Comment: @user3483203 nice remark crhis thanks ;)